# How do you make a code block in fogbugz Cases (tickets)?

Tags: markup, fogbugz

We have been using fogbugz and have been pasting code in tickets, but it always comes out hammered.

is there any way to denote that a block of text is code?

```
You know.. Like this
```

(edit) Is it possible to put some simple html to set the text apart or something??

(edit again)

- based on my research, html code *can* be put in the Cases, but not by the web UI.
- (in the DB) all Cases have a "text" field and an "HTML text" field for the message body, and then there is a flag that shows FogBugz which field to use.  Unfortunately, there is no way to enter HTML text via the FogBugz UI.  So this means that it is possible for a fogbugz plugin to be able to do the job, but none exist yet.

I will leave this one open for now, an accept an answer that points to a plugin or new feature that does this.

Comment: see also  http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/143/how-do-you-set-a-filter-for-cases-for-all-but-1-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Grab a recent version of FogBugz and get the [code formatting plugin](https://developers.kilnhg.com/Code/FogBugz/Group/FogBugz-Plugins/Files/Code%20Snippets?nr=).

Comment: it looks like someone is getting close to making one (see link above)

Answer (score 4):

For modern versions of FogBugz, there are two options:

1. On the case edit page, choose "rich text" edit mode and click the "code" button to get a code block (if you're copy/pasting, I find "paste and match style" to be a good way to make sure you don't bring in any unexpected formatting)
2. Surround the text you want to be a code block with `[code] ... [/code]` or `<code> ... </code>` tags to trigger the older code plugin mentioned in other answers

If you're running FogBugz 8.8.55 or lower, the second option is the only one available, and you'll need to make sure you've got the plugin installed. You can download it from the [plugin archive](https://developers.kilnhg.com/Code/FogBugz/Group/FogBugz-Plugins/Files/Code%20Snippets?nr=).

*Disclaimer: I work at Fog Creek and use FogBugz every day*

Answer (score 2):

The [Code Snippets plugin](https://developers.kilnhg.com/Code/FogBugz/Group/FogBugz-Plugins/Files/Code%20Snippets?nr=) in FogBugz 8 and above should now do what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You could always write a request on uservoice and someone might write a plugin to do it; or Fogcreek themselves might put it into a future version.